# Парсинг string в integer с комой [Jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть стринг который нужно перевести в значение, но хочу, что бы оно было с комой и желательно в переменной. Код написал для примера, поэтому в начале перевожу в стринг.

```
var intstringF = "3,2"; intstringF = intstringF.toString();
var intstringS = "9,1"; intstringS = intstringS.toString();
// ... parsing
var result = intstringF + intstringS;
$('#display').html(result);
```

Comment: Это вы так запятую обозвали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень понятно что такое "кома" и при чем тут "парсинг", но судя по всему требуется перевести строку числа с плавающей запятой в строку числа с плавающей точкой (то есть заменить запятую на точку), превратить стоку в число и произвести вычисление .... тогда как-то так:

```js
var intstringF = '3,2';
var intstringS = '9,1';
var strToFloat = function(str) {
  return parseFloat(str.replace(',', '.'))
};

var result = strToFloat(intstringF) + strToFloat(intstringS);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Иногда путаю языки. Впринципе все правильно, но на выходе нужно получить с стринга с запятой число с запятой, с которым можно свободно проворачивать какие либо манипуляции. Попробовал убрать замену символов в функции, но оно просто убрало запятую. И не совсем понятно почему, ведь toFloat переносит не целые значения..

Comment: @oles, Чисел с плавающей запятой в js не бывает, в js для дробной части используется точка. Так что с запятой можно получить только строку ...

Comment: а.. попробую реализовать с точкой. Спасибо)